# Doubly nested EL variables?

Tags: jsp, el

I'm using Spring MVC for my controller, and JSPs are my presentation layer.

Inside my Spring controller, I have:

```
model.put("issues", dataManager.getIssues());
model.put("functions", dataManager.getFunctions());
```

So now inside my JSP, I have access to

```
${requestScope['issues']}
${requestScope['functions']}
```

That's all well and good.  But in order for my code to be extensible, I would like to store the variable name `issues` and `functions` inside the database, which will then be accessible through a property on a `configs` object that's being looped over.  So what I'd like to end up with is something like the following:

```
<c:forEach items="${configs}" var="cfg">
    <c:if test="${cfg.configType == 'select'}">
        <th>${cfg.header}</th>
        <td><myTagLib:select values="${requestScope['${cfg.selectorName}']}" /></td>
    </c:if>
</c:forEach>
```

Where `${cfg.selectorName}` will hold either `issues` or `functions` in this example.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You're close. You only need to remove the nested `${}` since that's invalid syntax.

```
<myTagLib:select values="${requestScope[cfg.selectorName]}" />
```

Comment: @BalusC, I'm doing like **<c:set var="fullPath" value="${commandName}.courseList"/>
  <c:forEach items="${requestScope[fullPath}">
   <!-- ... -->
  </c:forEach>**. But I'm not able to get item list this way. please help.

Comment: **items='${request.getAttribute(fullPath)}'** is also not solving my purpose.